# Crystal Reports, not getting a value out of my formula to display in the report field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have records coming in to my report that contain fields "masterTypeId" and "amount". In my report footer I have an String field "@UnboundString30". The formula is:

```
(Local NumberVar r;
r := 0;
WhileReadingRecords; 
if{Table.masterTypeId}=2
then r := r + {Table.amount})
```

The Formula Workshop will save and close. When I run the report @UnboundString30 is always 0 despite there being many masterTypeIds of 2 and many amounts. It appears to me that I need to tell my field that it should be the value of r but I don't know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the return. Try to add on line, like this:

```
Local NumberVar r;
r := 0;
WhileReadingRecords; 
if{Table.masterTypeId}=2
then r := r + {Table.amount};
r; //this is the return
```